# My app is not showing JSON data from an URL

Tags: android, json

I am new to the android studio and I am trying to make my simple app get JSON data from URL i.e fetch JSON data from the server with Volley in Android Studio. When I debug on my device, it works fine but don't show any data and I am sure there is something wrong

my code:

```
package imo.meteoiraq;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RequestQueue rq;
TextView nameText,descriptionText,fbUrlText,youtubeUrlTxt;
    int humidity;
    int wind_speed;
    int temperature;
    String url="/stationlookupstation=I1410&units=metric&v=2.0&format=json";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        nameText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempText);
        descriptionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wind_speed);
        fbUrlText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidity);
        sendjsonrequest();
    }
public void  sendjsonrequest(){
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                temperature = response.getInt("temperature");
                wind_speed= response.getInt("wind_speed");
                humidity= response.getInt("type");

                nameText.setText(temperature);
                descriptionText.setText(humidity);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

my data json:

```
{
  "stations": {
    "I1410": {
      "updated": 1499668936,
      "ageh": 0,
      "agem": 0,
      "ages": 58,
      "type": "PWS",
      "wind_dir_degrees": 315,
      "wind_speed": 6.1,
      "wind_gust_speed": 11.1,
      "humidity": 10,
      "temperature": 40.5,
      "precip_rate": null,
      "precip_today": 0,
      "pressure": 1002.26,
      "dewpoint": null,
      "windchill": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `something wrong` you have to find out what exactly. Do you get any stacktrace of exception in the logcat? It might print something in `} catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first get JsonObject stations and I1410 , then use ages = I1410JO.getInt("ages");

```
JSONObject stationsJO = response.getJSONObject("stations");
JSONObject I1410JO = stationsJO.getJSONObject("I1410");
int ages = I1410JO.getInt("ages");
```

Comment: APP STOP WORKING

Comment: do you mean android moniter ?

Comment: if i make code like that get app stop working                 `JSONObject stationsJO = response.getJSONObject("stations");
                JSONObject I1410JO = stationsJO.getJSONObject("I1410");
                int ages = I1410JO.getInt("ages");
                int temperature = I1410JO.getInt("temperature");
                int humidity = I1410JO.getInt("humidity");


                nameText.setText(ages);
                youtubeUrlTxt.setText(temperature);
                descriptionText.setText(humidity);`

Comment: is very long data , see my last comment is but setText i get stop working `JSONObject stationsJO = response.getJSONObject("stations"); JSONObject I1410JO = stationsJO.getJSONObject("I1410"); int ages = I1410JO.getInt("ages"); int temperature = I1410JO.getInt("temperature"); int humidity = I1410JO.getInt("humidity"); nameText.setText(ages); youtubeUrlTxt.setText(temperature); descriptionText.setText(humidity);`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in the program.

1st issue already explained by Rasoul Miri about accessing stationsJO JSON object and then I1410JO JSON object.

2nd issue is that temperature is not of integer format but of double format and so you need to use I1410JO.getDouble("temperature") to get it.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your Url and you have not parsed response correctly.Send Correct Url with proper(GET or POST) method.